# Is there a website on which I can write and display MathJax/LaTeX?

Tags: discussion, support

MathJax/LaTeX is used in displaying math equations and expressions more elegantly. I've seen it most widely used in the mathematics department of StackExchange. What I am inquiring about is if there is a site that is used solely for the purpose of writing MathJax/LaTeX code and displaying its translation. I would like to show a person my custom example using MathJax, but I don't know of any way of showing it to him. What would be ideal is if I could give him a URL that takes him to a site showing the content I've written in MathJax. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online LaTeX Equation Editor --  http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 4):

How about the [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) on the Mathematics Meta site, where you indicate that MathJax is supported and enabled?

Comment: I found a website here from another question -- http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php but thanks for the help. I'll accept your question when I can.

Comment: @David you could also post your link as an answer...

Comment: @davidsleeps done :)